# How to configure Artifactory for Drupal 8 with packages.drupal.org/8 as source of drupal packages

Tags: composer-php, artifactory, drupal-8

I'm trying to setup an Artifactory **PHP Composer** repository.
In Artifactory repository configuration, we got to set 2 parameters:
    - URL
    - Registery URL

For Drupal 8 with packages.drupal.org/8 as source of drupal packages, I tried with those values:
    - URL: https://git.drupal.org/
 
    - Registery URL: https://packages.drupal.org/8

Error I've got:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package drupal/core could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.   Problem 2
>       - The requested package drupal/tvi could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.   Problem 3
>       - The requested package composer/installers could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

I followed *jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PHP+Composer+Repositories*

Is there anyone who successfully configured Artifactory PHP Composer for Drupal 8 and which parameters you used?

What I notice, there is little difference between the 2 composer repository

For packagist.org/packages.json

```
notify  "/downloads/%package%"
notify-batch    "/downloads/"
providers-url   "/p/%package%$%hash%.json"
search  "/search.json?q=%query%&type=%type%"
```

For packages.drupal.org/8/packages.json

```
notify-batch    "/8/downloads"
providers-url   "/8/%package%$%hash%.json"
search  "/8/search.json?s=%query%"
```

In Artifactory PHP Composer repo, is there any Hard Coding to report?

Ticket open and visible at https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15188

Thanks

Comment: The issue on the drupal side: https://www.drupal.org/project/project_composer/issues/2929078. 
To summarise: Proxying seems complex but composer 2 could resolve the problem. It could also come from JFrog ignoring packages.json